# Сравнение дат. PHP

Tags: php, битрикс

Не правильно работает условие, при котором сравниваются две даты: текущая и дата уже заданная. При выполнении этого условия `$date1 > $date2` должно отсылаться сообщение на почту, сейчас оно приходит в любом случае.

```
<?
  $date1 = new DateTime("now");
  $date2 = new DateTime($arProps['PRIK']['VALUE']);

  if ($date1 > $date2)  {
     $to = $arProps['EMAIL']['VALUE']; 
     $subject = 'ТЕСТ';
     $message = '<html><head><title>1</title></head><body><p>TEST</p></body>
     </html>';
     mail($to, $subject, $message);
     }

     var_dump($date1 == $date2); // принимает значение FALSE
     var_dump($date1 < $date2); // принимает значение FALSE
     var_dump($date1 > $date2); // принимает значение TRUE
```

Comment: а что у вас в `$arProps['PRIK']['VALUE']` ?

Comment: @Oleksandr значение, которое берется из поля. Например "12.10.2017"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно добавить формат, чтобы сравнение отработало. Для сравнения дат можно использовать ->format('Y-m-d').
Это решит проблему.

```
$date1 = new DateTime();
$date2 = new DateTime('12.10.2017');
$your_date = new DateTime($arProps['PRIK']['VALUE']);

if($date1->format('Y-m-d') > $date2->format('Y-m-d')) {

    // тут Ваш код

}
```

Comment: Вы не совсем правы. Сравнение объектов DateTime работает корректно, более того, если TimeZone объектов будет разный - объекты все равно корректно будут сравнены. [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961074/how-do-i-compare-two-datetime-objects-in-php-5-2-8). Единственное что, в памяти у меня почему-то засело, что это сделано было не сразу, но сейчас не могу найти - когда же это добавили.

Comment: Александр, я попробовал код представленный в описании вопроса - условие не отработало (в чем собственно и был вопрос). Предложенный мною вариант решает поставленную задачу. Не спорю, что решение не идеальное, поэтому буду благодарен, если Вы предложите код, который более элегантно подойдет для этой ситуации.

Comment: ну если Вы во втором значении берёте `12.10.2017`, то оно и понятно. Класс DateTime - это дата **и** время. Передавая в конструктор класса `12.10.2017` Вы создаёте дату со временем `00:00:00`. А `now` создаёт время именно "текущего момента" - час, минута, секунда - всё это учитывается. Как бы, `00:00:00` всегда будет меньше, чем любое другое время того же дня.

Comment: Я взял строку '12.10.2017' для примера. В сравнение вместо $date2 пойдет переменная $your_date, образованная из $arProps['PRIK']['VALUE'].

У Вас есть какие-либо предложения по исправлению кода для решения поставленного вопроса?

Answer (score 1):

а если так?

```
$ts = date('U');

$now = getdate($ts);

$tt = $now['year'].'-'.$now['mon'].'-'.$now['mday'];

$your_date = new DateTime('12.10.2017');

$date2 = getdate($your_date);

$tt1 = $date2['year'].'-'.$date2['mon'].'-'.$date2['mday'];

if($tt1 > $tt){

}
```

если дата из бд получена  то просто

```
$ts = date('U');

$now = getdate($ts);

$tt = $now['year'].'-'.$now['mon'].'-'.$now['mday'];

$your_date = '2017-1012';

if($your_date > $tt){

}
```